# formik with custo style (ant design)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, ant-design-pro, react-forms

I made a reusable formik form, but I want to use ant select instead of formik select. the Error message is not working with ant design and I dont know how to configure that.
I need to show the error message when it's not validated. in console.log there is no problem it wworks perfect as i change the ant select. But the errortext does not shows

```
import React from "react";
import { Formik } from "formik";
import {Form} from 'antd'
import * as Yup from "yup";
import FormikController from "../components/Forms/FormikController";
const city = [
  { key: "option 1", value: "option1" },
  { key: "option 2", value: "option2" },
  { key: "option 3", value: "option3" },
  { key: "option 4", value: "option4" },
 ];
const Contact = () => {
  const initialValues = {
    whoYouAre: "",
    email: "",
    message: "",
  };
  const validationSchema = Yup.object({
    whoYouAre :Yup.string().required(),
    email :Yup.string().required()
  });
  return (
      <Container className="contact">
            <h5 className="mb-4">Contact</h5>
            <Formik
              initialValues={initialValues}
              validationSchema={validationSchema}
              // onSubmit={handleAddData}
              validateOnMount
            >
              {(formik) => (
                <Form className="w-100">
                    <FormikController
                      control="selectsearch"
                      options={city}
                      formik={formik}
                      name="whoYouAre"
                      label="Please Tell Us Who You Are"
                    />
                    <FormikController
                      control="input"
                      type="text"
                      name="email"
                      label="Email"
                    />
                    <FormikController
                     control="textarea"
                      name="message"
                      rows="8"
                      label="Message"
                    />
                    <div>
                      <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
                        Send
                      </Button>
                    </div>
                </Form>
              )}
            </Formik>
      </Container>
  );
};
export default Contact;
```

and here the resusable select that i used from ant design

```
import React from "react";
import { Form,Select } from "antd";
import { ErrorMessage } from "formik";
import TextError from "./TextError";
const { Option } = Select;
const SearchSel = (props) => {
const { label, name, options ,formik, ...rest } = props;
console.log(formik);
return (
  <Form.Item className="mb-3">
    <Select
      showSearch
      size="large"
      optionFilterProp="children"
      placeholder={label}
      name={name}
      onChange={(value) => formik.setFieldValue("whoYouAre", value)}
    >
      {options.map((option) => {
        return (
          <Option key={option.value} value={option.value}>
            {option.key}
          </Option>
        );
      })}
    </Select>
    <ErrorMessage name={name} component={TextError} />
  </Form.Item>
);
```

};
export default SearchSel;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your default state is `""` isn't right I believe. You probably want `null`.

Secondly, your `Select` is not correctly bound to the form state. You need to add `value`.

Moreover, you also need to add `defaultActiveFirstOption={false}` as that may be immediately selecting the first item on the initial state.

**Finally, and probably most importantly**,  probably need to bind the fields `blur` such that it sets the field as touched. `ErrorMessage` won't show the error [unless it thinks the user touched the field](https://formik.org/docs/api/errormessage#:%7E:text=if%20that%20field%20has%20been%20visited):

```
    <Select
      showSearch
      size="large"
      optionFilterProp="children"
      placeholder={label}
      name={name}
      value={formik.values.whoYouAre}
      defaultActiveFirstOption={false}
      onChange={(value) => formik.setFieldValue("whoYouAre", value)}
      onBlur={() => formik.setFieldTouched("whoYouAre", true)}
    >
```